# aws instances EC2. It turns off automatically. As you can turn it on automatically

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an aws instances EC2. But lately it's stopped working for reasons I don't know about.
Does AWS have a way that if it shuts down, it automatically turns on the instance?.

Same way I have an instance of staging. Same thing happened to him.

Comment: What do you mean by "if it shuts down"? Do you mean "if an application stops responding" or do you mean "the instance is in the Stopped state"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, follow this tutorial but make the cloudwatch event fire when an EC2 instance is stopped instead. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/LogEC2InstanceState.html

One general strategy for reacting to events in AWS is:

1. Define a CloudWatch Event that "listens" for a certain event to happen
2. Define a Lambda function that gets triggered when the event happens
3. Write some code in the Lambda function that does something

In your case this would be

1. Your cloudwatch event listens for the "EC2 instance stopped" event
2. Your lambda function gets triggered, and cloudwatch passes in your stopped EC2 instance's details as a parameter
3. You write some lambda code that starts the EC2 instance